# How to mix concrete cement

Tags: concrete

How do i make sure i have the right air in concrete cement if i'm mixing at home.So that the concrete is stronger and won't crack in cold winters. I'm pouring a small walk way about a meter of concrete.

Comment: Are there any instructions printed on the bag of cement you've purchased?

Comment: I usually vibrate walls to take the air out, well the big pockets. For a sidewalk use a mixer they work the same way a truck dose.

Answer (score 3):

To get air entrained concrete similar to that which you'd get from a ready mix delivery, you'll need to add an air entraining agent to your mix.

Without getting in to serious mix design, for all practical purposes, a 4:2:1 (stone : sand : cement) mix will likely suffice for a walkway.

If you're really bothered about cracking, include a layer of smaller gauge reinforcement (eg A142) as an anti-crack mesh.

Answer (score 1):

My understanding is that air entrained concrete is only possible with ready-mixed concrete.